# How to get Ubuntuone password in Terminal

Tags: apt

When trying to run Sudo-apt-get in terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 it asks for password. I do not remember any password. how to reset password/ solve this problem

Comment: You should try with password of user who runs sudo command.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, root user has no password and is locked so that nobody can log into this account. To gain root privileges for system administration, an admin user (member of usergroup sudo) may use the sudo command to run 1 command as root.
So if you did not give root a password for any reason, the password sudo is asking for is your own, the same you need to type for login. You had to chose one when you installed Ubuntu.
If you forgot your OWN user password (maybe because you use automatic login), you have to reset it following the advice of *Sachin Kamath* above. (Copy of his [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword))